Flutter IOS Build: Undefined name 'REG_SAM_FLAGS'
flutter Failed to build ../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32_registry-1.1.3/lib/src/models/access_rights.dart:9:12: Error: Undefined name 'REG_SAM_FLAGS'.
Flutter flow recently started throwing this error when I build my ios project through there system and locally. Seams to be some windows related dep but its IOS?
I tried all the normal ways i've fixed package issues in the past with flutter, cleared cache, removed the lock files, and rebuilt things, but no go.
Anyone

I am also having this problem; did you find a solution?

Not yet. :/ It's also happening on the deploy feature from the flutter flow UI.

Looks like theres an issue filed with the underlying package with the same error
https://github.com/halildurmus/win32_registry/issues/18

It looks like this is because the package that flutter flow was using in the pubspec.yaml is out of date. And is referencing some types that don't exist. It needs to be updated to the latest version and should build properly.
In my pubspec.yaml:
dependency_overrides:
  http: 1.2.0
  uuid: ^4.0.0
  win32: 5.0.9

Change to:
win32: 5.4.0

Here's the underlying github package tracking the issue.
https://github.com/halildurmus/win32_registry/issues/18
Hope this helps!
